# Set background image of ionic 2 app

Tags: css, angular, background, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to set an image as a brackground of every pages of my Ionic 2 app.

I know how to do that in the HTML or in the CSS of one page (which I could do in all of them).

I know how to set the background color of the whole app in `theme\variables.scss`

```
$background-color: map-get($map: $colors, $key: primary);
```

(for example)

But it seems like doing the same with

```
$background-image: url('assets/images/background-image.jpg');
```

does not work. Even if that exact same line in one page's css works.

```
.class-name-here{
    background-image: url('assets/images/background-image.jpg');
}
```

Would it be possible to set an image as the whole app's default background in Ionic 2/ Ionic 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it as shown below:

**Note:** Need to use global `scss` file. That is `app.scss`

*app.scss*

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url('./assets/images/background-image.jpg');;
}
```

Comment: Alright, I previously tried to add the same `$background-image: url('assets/images/background-image.jpg');` there which was not working. Your way works perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)